# Storing Files in an Incremental Number

Tags: java, android

I was wondering how issit possible that I can store images or text or file of anytype in an incremental format, for example,

image1,
image2,
image3,
image4.

such that even if i have them stored at different times, i will be able to get the largest number for that moment and add one to it.

Answer (score 2):

I like Dr. Dredel's answer if the file names are limited. If not, then the SharedPreference would need to store an index for each unique name. If that's ok, then wonderful =). If that's not ok, you can continually increment your file name until the file does not exist. For example:

```
File newFile = new File(myFileName);
while (newFile.exists()) {
    myFileName = increment(myFileName);
    newFile  = new File(myFileName);
}
```

A sample increment method is:

```
public String increment(final String pString) {
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = pString.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (!isNumeric(pString.substring(i))) {
            index = i + 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    String incrementedId;

    // If whole string is numeric, must be integer or double:
    if (index < 0) {
        incrementedId = incrementNumber(pString);
    }
    // If string has no index, assume this is the second occurrence:
    else if (index == pString.length()) {
        incrementedId = pString + "2";
    }
    // Otherwise, increment end index:
    else {
        incrementedId =
                pString.substring(0, index)
                        + incrementNumber(pString.substring(index));
    }

    return incrementedId;
}

private String incrementNumber(final String pString) {
    String num;
    try {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(pString);
        num = String.valueOf(id + 1);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        double id = Double.parseDouble(pString);
        num = String.valueOf(id + 1);
    }
    return num;
}
```

You can implement isNumeric as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

If they are stored in the SD Card, you could first get a list of the files using the `list()` method of the `File` class. And use the `Arrays#sort()` method to know which one is the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to store your last number in a SharedPreference and just go to it every time you need the next one in the sequence.

Alternatively (and I don't recommend this) you can loop through a while(new File("image"+i++).exists() )... but you can see how ugly that is.

Comment: Hmmm, but then you have redundant data: The highest file number is stored both in the preference and also in the file system directory. What if they get out of sync? For example, is it possible for someone to manually delete files? Or worse, to manually create one, or for some other program to create one? I'd rather rely on reading the directory: that's the real authority.

Comment: As purely an FYI, "while(new File("image"+i++).exists() )" would fail if the filename already ended in a number. "image-000" would be "image-0001" instead of being "image-001"

Comment: @Teddy Yueh - also purely as FYI, a string literal "image" is not a variable and does not therefore have any possibility of being "image-000". if we are being pedantic and nit picking about other peoples code suggestions. :-)

Comment: I automatically replaced "image" with a variable as that would probably be the way to go. I like his answer. I say so in the very beginning of my own =).

Answer (score 0):

If you read in all the filenames and sort alphabetically the highest number should come to the top (or bottom, depending on the sort). Then you can strip the "image" and ".jpg" off, convert to an int, and add 1.

Looking at the date on the files is another option, but that could introduce bugs - i.e. if there's a daylight savings change, or if the time/date on the device is updated.

The other alternative is to maintain the highest number in a preference or other counter, assuming you know it will always be available for you (but if you want to restart at 1 if the files are copied off an SD card, or whatever, then you'll just have to look at the file names), and you'll have issues if apps are uninstalled and reinstalled.

Comment: I'd use a filter to get only files matching the desired pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I've always done this by creating an object for "file1", testing if it exists, if so try "file2", etc in a loop. But the idea of getting a list and sorting it is probably more efficient. (When I do this, it's always been in a context where I expect few if any duplicates, so I don't normally have to try more than 2 or 3. If you really expect there to be hundreds, trial and error is probably pretty inefficient.)

Answer (score 0):

How about using this kind of code (and use `FileNames` to match your numbering can start anywhere and you can get rid of older files):

```
  import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

/**
 * This class helps creating Strings with incremental number value in it
 * (such as incremental fileNames).
 * <P/>
 * Instances must be created with a simplified pattern where the character
 * '#' is the place holder for a number (integer).
 * <P/>
 * Then other Strings containing the same pattern can be submitted
 * with method <TT>submit</TT>  and in the end the <TT>getMaxString()</TT> method will yield
 * the next numbered String.
 * <P/>
 * So for example :
 * <PRE>
 *      String pattern = "aName#.something";
 *  NumberedStringGenerator generator = new NumberedStringGenerator(pattern) ;
 *  System.out.println(" first :" + generator.getMaxString());
 *  // will yield : "aName0.something"
 *  generator.submit("aName0.something") ;
 *  generator.submit("aName11.something") ;
 *  generator.submit("aName1.something") ;
 *  System.out.println(" max :" + generator.getMaxString());
 *  // will yield : "aName12.something"
 * </PRE>
 *
 */

public class NumberedStringGenerator {
    private MessageFormat messageFormat ;
    private int max =-1;
    private int min = -1 ;

    /**
     * creates a generator that will compare Strings and will yield the
     * next incremented String.
     * @param simplePattern a String with a '#' character as number placeholder
     */
    public NumberedStringGenerator(String simplePattern) {
        String realPattern = simplePattern.replace("#", "{0,number,integer}");
        messageFormat = new MessageFormat(realPattern) ;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param candidate any String that possibly matches the initial pattern
     * @return true if matched false otherwise
     */
    public boolean submit(String candidate) {
        try {
            Object[] parsed = messageFormat.parse(candidate) ;
            int val = ((Long) parsed[0]).intValue();
            if(val > max) {
                max =val ;
            }
            if(min == -1) { min = val ;}
            else if (val < min ) {
                min = val ;
            }
            return true ;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
           return false ;
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return a new String that has the highest number immediately after the highest matched String
     */
    public String getMaxString() {
        return messageFormat.format(new Integer[] {max+1});
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return the smallest numbered String being submitted or null if none matched
     */
    public String getMinString() {
        if(min == -1) return null;
        return messageFormat.format(new Integer[] {min});
    }
}
```